# Visualização de Colors e criação de novas

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Estou precisando fazer uso da [classe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.colors.aspx) `Colors` definida no *namespace* `Windows.UI`.

São muitas cores disponíveis e eu estou precisando encontrar uma forma ou um lugar para para ver uma pré-visualização dessas cores, pois só pelo nome fica difícil saber o resultado.

É possível criar novas cores seja baseado em RGB, seja baseado em hexadecimal (HTML)?

Answer (score 3):

Veja se o exemplo de cores mostrado [nessa documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colors?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) te ajuda.

Tem alguns softwares de Color Picker que fazem pelo nome (imagino que esses sejam nomes universais). [Um online que faz isso](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp).

O ideal seria fazer um código que gerasse todas elas, inclusive com o conteúdo que deseja. Dá para fazer isso facilmente usando reflexão lendo todos membros da classe e usando as cores no que quiser. Na verdade [alguém já fez isso](http://www.skylark-software.com/2009/05/wpf-colors-static-classes-and.html) com outra classe de cores e deve ser muito fácil adaptar para sua necessidade. Lá tem exemplos também.

É possível usar qualquer da palheta RGB, ou seja, cerca de 16 milhões de cores, normalmente usado o hexadecimal (ex.: `#C010FF`). A classe é uma facilitadora com cores bastante usadas.

Note que onde espera uma cor espera uma estrutura `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.aspx` que é composto por 3 bytes, uma para cada cor básica (existe uma quarta de camada alfa, mas isso não importa nesse contexto). Então o que você coloca ali é um número que você pode por em hexadecimal ou decimal. A cores desta classe são apenas nomes para valores predefinidos, você não coloca um nome lá e sim um número, o nome é só pra te ajudar. Não custa ressaltar que variáveis são apenas nomes para uma posição na memória, que possui valores. Não existe nada de especial nisso.

O que tem de especial é que o XAML identifica sozinho se está usando um nome ou valor. Isso é feito internamente através de *type converters*, mas você nem precisa saber disto para usar.

Comment: E como eu faria para usar uma cor que não está na classe?
No meu caso eu estou mudando a cor da barra de título e dos botões da janela com `var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView ( ).TitleBar;` e `titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.DimGray`. No meu caso eu quero um cinza mais escuro que os disponíveis na classe.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva usando o hexadecimal que define uma cor, conforme eu falei na resposta. Onde aceita uma cor aceita a estrutura https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.aspx. O que põe ali é sempre um código de cor com 3 bytes, um para cada cor. A classe `Colors` só possui alguns números prontos para uso em nomes específicos.

Comment: Na verdade minha dúvida é de que forma eu devo inserir o hexadecimal. Ou seja, como String ou em algum método que receba uma string hex e converta para um `Color`.
Usei a resposta do @rubStackOverflow, e descobri o método `Color.FromArgb(int a, int r, int g, int b)` . Funcionando bem agora, porém se houver uma forma de passar um hex, acho mais prático.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva você viu a documentação que eu *linkei*? Lá tem exemplos de uso. Se for XAML pode usar o hexadecimal direto como *string*, cado contrário terá que preencher cada propriedade (cada cor) da estrutura com um número. Você pode fazer usando notação hexadecimal ou decimal, se preferir.

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei não existe uma forma de modificar as cores da barra de título e botões de fechar, maximizar e minimizar da janela via XAML. Estou fazendo isso via código C# em `App.xaml.cs`.
Pesquisei mais um pouco e parece que não existe nada pronto, onde a solução é criar um método que faça a conversão como em [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782399/converting-a-string-hex-to-color-in-windows-phone-runtime-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782399/converting-a-string-hex-to-color-in-windows-phone-runtime-c-sharp)

Comment: Apenas corrigindo. Os parâmetros de `FromArgb()` são do tipo `byte` e não `int`

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva é possível.

Comment: Pensando bem, você tem razão. `App.xaml.cs` nada mais é que o code-behind do `App.xaml`.

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa (paga) `Resharper` (obviamente utilizar esta ferramenta somente para visualizar e criar novas cores não é viável)

```
MeuBotao.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,0,0,255));
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]